# html varying image file url when friends access

Tags: html

I am using html to make a website with 2 friends using google drive to share it. Because it isn't an actual website and only a file to open, how can we make the file:/// link find the image when it varies in place for everyone?
Below is an example of how it varies

```
file:///C:/Users/Alex/Alexs%20Google%20Drive/sharedfolder/image.gif to file:///C:Users/Friend/Friends%20Google%20Drive/sharedfolder/image.gif
```

It will only work on the computer whose link it points to and we can't make one that points to all of them on the same computer.

Comment: Just use relative paths, assuming index.HTML is also in the drive

Answer (score 1):

You must to use relative paths, and not absolute paths:

### Absolute path

file://C:/folder/file.gif

### Relative path

../folder/file.gif

If your project is in `file://C:/appweb` and your images in `file://C:/appweb/images` the link to image should be `images/image.gif`

Answer (score 0):

If the html file is located in the same folder as the image, you should be able to point directly to the image, without the use of file:/// protocol.

Example:

```
<body>
    <img src="image.jpg" alt="my image" />
</body>
```

And the file structure in the folder is like:

- index.html
- image.jpg
- image2.jpg